# gvisTable number format - trailing zeros removed

Tags: r, googlevis

I can specify the number format just as the documentation says : "The format string is a subset of the ICU pattern set" so for example "#.##".  However trailing zeros are trimmed - I want them shown so that the decimal point always aligns in a column, regardless of the number value.

Example:

```
plot(gvisTable(mtcars[1:4,],formats=list(drat="#.##")))
```

produces:

[image]